# Native Ad Admob to Custom List Adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, admob, native

I'm struggling to find a way to add a native ad within my app on Android.

MainActivity Class:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

        final String[] numbers = {"one","two", "", "three", "four", "five","six","seven" "eight","nine", "ten" "eleven","twelve", "thirteen"};


        Integer[] images = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
        };

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), mobileArray, images);

        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);

        list=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

CustomListAdapter Class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] numbers;
    private final Integer[] imgid;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] numbers, Integer[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.listv, itemname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.numbers=numbers;
        this.imgid=imgid;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listv, null,true);

        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgid);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        txtTitle.setText(numbers[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Number: "numbers[position]);

        return rowView;

    };
}
```

I want to add the native add within a particular index in array, ideally where it shows "". I'm trying to add the adView into the adapter but unsure how to do this.

Edit:

listv layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgid"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#4CBE99" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="345x80"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2793859312"></com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
```

Comment: What all position you should show..? and add your listv.xml layout

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran sorry I don't understand :/

Comment: You want to show in every position..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran no only in the 3rd index position 3. thanks

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I have added the listv.xml thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    private NativeExpressAdView adView;

    private NativeExpressAdView getAddView() {
        if (adView != null) {
            return adView;
        }
        adView = new NativeExpressAdView(context);

        adView.setAdUnitId("[your unit id]");
        adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 80));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);

        return adView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add, null, true);

//        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.addView);

        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgid);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        txtTitle.setText(numbers[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
        extratxt.setText("Number: " + numbers[position]);

        if (position == 2) {
            linearLayout.addView(getAddView());
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return rowView;

    }

    ;
}
```

Layour xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgid"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#4CBE99"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but for my main xml I had the native ad xml with a test code and I need to use this to test it. I have edited it above.

Comment: Just add this 2 line **adView.setAdUnitId("[your unit id]");
            adView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, 80));** it will work fine, And Please remove your Add uid from the question.

Comment: Thanks but the ad doesn't show. I can see this in the logs:                                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Try to remove **if (adView != null) {
            return adView;
        }** in getAddView() and check

Comment: Can't find the error, trying to look for one but can't at the moment.

Comment: Try to create a view with false **View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add, null, false);**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151991/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-samantha).

Comment: Still can't get the Native Ad to show tried different things not showing

Comment: I can get this to work now but the problem is my ImageView on the left is covering the Ad how can i remove all the views just for this position=2 so the ad fits in nicely?

Comment: Okay will accept now, can do with visibility gone. Thanks for you help Muk